# How do I change the window theme using bash?

Tags: themes, gconf, gsettings

In Ubuntu 12.04, how will I be able to set the gnome window theme with a bash command?

This no longer works (it used to in the previous releases)

```
gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/theme 'Adwaita'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `gsettings` command to change the theme now. This would be the functional equivalent to your command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme Adwaita`